# ASP.Net Web Forms SignalR Object has no Method

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I added SignalR to an existing ASP.Net 4 Web Forms application.  Created a new folder called Hubs and added a Hub like so:

```
[HubName("UpdatesHub")]
public class UpdatesHub : Hub
{
    public void DownloadUpdates()
    {
        // Code Removed
    }
}
```

Added the RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); to Application_Start and added the following to the page:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.1.js"></script>

<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
        var upd = $.connection.UpdatesHub;

        // Code Removed

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#btnDownload').click(function () {
                upd.server.DownloadUpdates();
            });
        });

    });

</script>
```

But whenever I click the button I just get "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'DownloadUpdates'".  I have tried removing and readding signalr via NuGet but can't seem to get this to work, help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SignalR camelCases the method names on the server.](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs#invoking-methods-on-the-server) Try checking if `downloadUpdates()` exists.

Comment: Easiest way to check is to navigate to "/signalr/hubs" directly in your browser to see the Javascript code which SignalR creates.